# How can SSRS find all values of a CASE?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table with information by different groups, but some groups belong to the same division and my boss wants to visualize data by division. I have set a CASE to change the ID's to become just one in hopes that the SSRS parameter could find all records assigned to that ID, but it doesn't seem to show me all the 'converted' ID's, so I am clearly doing something wrong.

```
SELECT  
case when app.application_id in (41,56,48,107) then 41 else app.application_id end as application_id,
  case when service_c like '%startex%' then 5 else servicetype_id end as ServiceTypeId,
  sc.App_Desc,
  service_c Service
            
  from table..Application app            
  inner join table..servicecode sc on app.application_id = sc.Application_Id            
  inner join table..ApplicationServiceCatalog ac on app.service_id = ac.Service_Id            
  where app.application_id = @Parameter –-this is what the user will select in SSRS
  and reportdate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

I am not an expert in SSRS or SQL so I am wondering if the issue could be fixed directly in the query, or if there is a setup I need to configure in SSRS for this to work.

The data looks something like this:

```
application_id  App_Desc    Division
41  Group 1 EastDivision
41  Group 1 EastDivision
41  Group 1 EastDivision
41  Group 1 EastDivision
41  Group 1 EastDivision
41  Group 2 EastDivision
41  Group 2 EastDivision
41  Group 2 EastDivision
41  Group 2 EastDivision
41  Group 3 EastDivision
41  Group 3 EastDivision
41  Group 3 EastDivision
41  Group 3 EastDivision
41  Group 3 EastDivision
```

The Groups originally have different ID's, but I need to group them as I am pulling details from another table that only has the ID for Primary Key.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
where app.application_id = @Parameter
```

You could filter on your `CASE` statement like this:

```
where case when app.application_id in (41,56,48,107) then 41 else app.application_id end = @Parameter
```

This would allow the report to filter on the grouped ID. Is this what you were looking for?